# Can't load UI or use TTY

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, tty

Today when I tried to log into Ubuntu (20.04) I noticed multiple problems:

1. Login screen displayed with completely incorrect resolution.
2. When I type my password, getting an error `Failed to start session`.
3. After 10-20 seconds login screen just freezes. When I try to type a password I don't see any changes text field. Also cursor stops blinking.
4. I have tried to switch to TTY by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1`. Once I have succeeded to switch to console, but even log in, but after 10-20 second console also freezes. Sometimes console is not loading completely, only a few black lines are drawn on top of Ubuntu login screen.
5. When I try to use recovery mode, loading doesn't move forward step: `[OK] Finished flush Journal to Persistent Storage`

Comment: Have you tried booting from live media and see if that has same problems?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything works.